# Importing React component in Play framework

Tags: java, reactjs, playframework

I am trying to use React to render the UI in Play framework. I have my react Components in multiple files and am trying to import the Components from one file to another but I always get the following error on compilation
"**Illegal Import Declaration"** and **Illegal export Declaration**

### Component1.jsx

```
 import {Component2} from './Component2'
 class Component1 extends React.Component{
    render(){
       <div><h1>Hello</h1>
         <Component2 />
         </div>
    }
 }

ReactDOM.render(<Component1 />, document.getElementById('headerLine'))
```

### Component2.jsx

```
export class Component2 extends React.Component{
   render(){
   <div><h1>World</h1></div>
   }
}
```

The play framework version being used is 2.4.2 .
React version 0.14.3.
What can be the possible issue here?
Do I need to use bundlers like webpack or browserify? If Yes how do I do it with play framework?

Comment: regarding the code above, not sure if this is the cause, but the render methods should be defined like this : render() { .... }. I think that render(<div>...</div>) is an invalid syntax (check first example here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html). Another thing is that the render method must return one element, not 2 like the first render method. So, the Component2 should be in the <div> element.

Comment: I  am facing same problem, but seeing you solved it , I wounder if you used sbt-webpack or wirte your own module?

Comment: I referred the following link : [link]( https://github.com/nouhoum/play-react-webpack) to get it working. It does not use sbt-webpack but makes use of  Play hook as mentioned in the answer below

Comment: Hi I tried the link and when I run sbt run I get java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "webpack" (in directory "/Volumes/Data/play-react-webpack"): error=2, No such file or directory
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
 at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
 at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will need to *bundle* your javascript while browsers don't add support for [ES6 modules](http://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module)

To do that in the play framework you have two options, one is using [sbt-web](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-web) which is the standard way to deal with assets in play framework (which I quite don't like) or you can simple use webpack as you would normally do and add a *hook* in your build to bundle your app. Here is the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SBTCookbook) on how to call another process before starting the server.

Comment: Used the second approach, ie. using webpack and Play hooks and got the app running.